# Run-time error '91' vba-access

Tags: ms-access, vba

Hey my program checks for a zip file and copies it to another directory. However I stumbled upon "Run time error '91' object variable or With block variable not set" on oApp when I compiled it.

```
Sub UnZip(Fname As Variant)

    Dim oApp As Object
    Dim FileNameFolder As Variant

    FileNameFolder = "P:\"
    Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    oApp.Namespace(FileNameFolder).CopyHere oApp.Namespace(Fname).items

End Sub
```

What's the problem?

I'm using MS access 2010

Answer (score 1):

.Copyhere works on folder objects.

```
Sub UnZip(Fname As Variant)
    dim objShell
    dim objFolder

    set objShell = CreateObject("shell.application")
    set objFolder = objShell.NameSpace("P:")

    If not objFolder is nothing then
        objFolder.CopyHere(Fname)
    End If

End Sub
```

Fname must include both path and filename with extension.

Comment: In my case, I got my Fname to be a FolderItem. However when I run objFolder.CopyHere(Fname), I get the same error "'91' object variable or With block variable not set"

Comment: Fname should be passed to the unzip sub as a string.